# Add dynamic margins using UI Kit

Tags: html, css, flexbox, getuikit

I need to add margin between the cards, but only internal margins.

The code below is responsive.

- Large Screens has 4 Cards.
- Medium Screens has 3 Cards.
- Small Screens
  has 2 Cards.
- Micro Screens has 1 Cards.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.7/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.7/css/uikit-core-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-child-width-1-1 uk-child-width-1-2@s uk-child-width-1-3@m uk-child-width-1-4@l uk-flex-wrap">
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
</div>
```

I want to add margins between the cards dynamically. What is the best way?

- Large Screens has 4 Cards.

  - Margin left for the second, the third, and the fourth card card.
- Medium Screens has 3 Cards.

  - Margin left for the second and the third card.
- Small Screens
  has 2 Cards.

  - Margin left for the second card.
- Micro Screens has 1 Cards.

  - Without margins

I want to solve this with `CSS` or `UI Kit classes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think UIkit offers special [margin](https://getuikit.com/docs/margin) classes based on the screen size but you can target them using media queries like this. If you add a margin to the columns, it will wrap to a new row. You can try to mimic the margin by using a white border on the left.

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) { /* Large screen width in UI Kit */
  .uk-card:nth-of-type(4n+2), .uk-card:nth-of-type(4n+3), .uk-card:nth-of-type(4n+4) { /* Select the 2nd, 3rd and 4th element of the row when showing 4 columns */
    border-left: 10px solid white;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 960px)  and (max-width: 1200px) { /* Medium screen width in UI Kit */
  .uk-card:nth-of-type(3n+2), .uk-card:nth-of-type(3n+3) { /* Select the 2nd, 3rd element of the row when showing 3 columns */
    border-left: 10px solid white;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 640px)  and (max-width: 960px) { /* Small screen width in UI Kit */
  .uk-card:nth-of-type(2n+2) { /* Select the 2nd element of the row when showing 2 columns */
    border-left: 10px solid white;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.7/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.7/css/uikit-core-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-child-width-1-1 uk-child-width-1-2@s uk-child-width-1-3@m uk-child-width-1-4@l uk-flex-wrap">
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">Foo</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible ignore hidden cards?

Comment: Depends on the context. I would suggest you to open a new question please.

Comment: You may want to set a inbuilt class and then separate them using `:not` in CSS.